# CPU percent being used by GC using JMX

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, monitoring, jmx

I am trying to write a program that uses JMX to find the percentage of CPU being used for GC activity by the JVM at that moment of time(or for a small subset of time say 1 sec), similar to what JVisualVM. Using JMX i am able to find the GarbageCollectionTime the time the lasdt GC cycle started and ended. But haven't yet found a way to convert this information into CPU utilization for GC.

Comment: JVisualVM is using jstat API, not JMX, to display CPU usage graph

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't be able to find the answer programatically. The GC will use 100% of the available CPU. The real question is "How many CPU are available ?"

- The serial GC (`-XX:+UseSerialGC`) will use **one** CPU.
- The parallel collectors (`-XX:+UseParallelGC`, `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC` and `-XX:+UseParNewGC`) will use **the number of CPU you give** (`-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N`), or all of them if you do not specify a number
- The mostly-concurrent collectors (`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` and `-XX:+UseG1GC`) will use **the number of CPU you give** (`-XX:ConcGCThreads=N`), or ĥalf of them if you do not specify a number

Note that, with CMS and G1, you can set some goals to the GC with the following options :

- `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=X` will set the maximum pause time goal in milliseconds:
- `-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=<X>` will set the minimum interval goal between two GC cycles

Source : http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/

You can find tips to parse iCMS logs on [this page](http://www.pingtimeout.fr/2013/04/extracting-icms-data-from-garbage.html), and tips on GC tuning on [this page](http://www.pingtimeout.fr/2013/03/petclinic-performance-tuning-about.html).

Hope that helps !

Comment: What i meant was to get information similar to what you can find using VisualVM. At a given point of time GC uses an entire core(or more) or it doesn't when i say percentage it is more over a period of time like say percentage of the time spent in GC in last 1 second.

Comment: Serial and Parallel GC are STW and start when your memory pools are full, so you cannot limit them. You can set goals to CMS and G1, I have edited my answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this information is not available via JMX (IMHO VisualVM display display incorrect GC CPU time).

You can use `jstat -gc <pid>` to collected garage collection CPU usage for your JVM.

`jstat -gc <pid> 1s` will produce something like this

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
6528.0 6528.0 6523.9 6528.0 52480.0  51600.0  2097152.0  1697279.8  21248.0 5647.8     39    6.873   5     11.685   18.559
6528.0 6528.0  0.0   6528.0 52480.0  13355.5  2097152.0  1794839.9  21248.0 5649.8     41    7.322   5     11.685   19.008
6528.0 6528.0  0.0   6528.0 52480.0  27790.8  2097152.0  1884439.9  21248.0 5649.8     43    7.646   5     11.685   19.332
6528.0 6528.0  0.0   6528.0 52480.0  50942.9  2097152.0  1974055.9  21248.0 5649.8     46    7.969   5     11.685   19.654
```

- YGCT - CPU time is seconds consumed by young generation collections since start of JVM
- FGCT - CPU time is seconds consumed by full collections since start of JVM
- GCT - sum of above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [jvmtop](http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop/) may help you out (have a look at the `GC` column)

```
 JvmTop 0.3 alpha (expect bugs)  amd64  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.12
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

  PID MAIN-CLASS      HPCUR HPMAX NHCUR NHMAX    CPU     GC    VM USERNAME   #T DL
 3370 rapperSimpleApp  165m  455m  109m  176m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        21
11272 ver.resin.Resin [ERROR: Could not attach to VM]
27338 WatchdogManager   11m   28m   23m  130m  0.00%  0.00% S6U37 web        31
19187 m.jvmtop.JvmTop   20m 3544m   13m  130m  0.93%  0.47% S6U37 web        20
16733 artup.Bootstrap  159m  455m  166m  304m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        46
```